# How to create OpenAL Context in LWJGL 3

Tags: java, lwjgl, openal

How can I create the OpenAL-Context in LWJGL3?

I read, that you have to use "ALcontext", but that class doesn't exit in the current Release-Build.

(LWJGL 3.0.0 build 90)

Answer (score 2):

Several utility classes for OpenAL and OpenCL have been removed in LWJGL 3, so you will have to manually create an OpenAL context using alXXX functions.

From the [release notes](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=6157.0) (emphasis original):

> - **Dropped** ALDevice/ALContext wrappers from OpenAL and CLPlatform/CLDevice wrappers from OpenCL. ([#152](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/152))

[Issue #152](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/152#issuecomment-198144176) provides example code:

> Opening the default device and creating a default context with the above changes and no error checks:
>
> ```
> // Can call "alc" functions at any time
> long device = alcOpenDevice((ByteBuffer)null);
> ALCCapabilities deviceCaps = ALC.createCapabilities(device);
>
> long context = alcCreateContext(device, (ByteBuffer)null);
> alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
> AL.createCapabilities(deviceCaps);
> // Can now call "al" functions
> ```